# Как разбить файл на массив строк?

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день. Я читаю файл, и надо занести строки в массив, т.е. первая строка — это 0-й элемент массива, 2-я - это 1-й элемент и т.д.

Пытаюсь решить задачу так:

```
$Data = explode('\n',$content);
```

Но такой вариант не работает. `\n` - воспринимается как символ, а не как новая строка. 
Как мне разбить файл на строки?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы запись `\n` воспринималась как символ переноса строки, а не как пара символов `\` и `n`, ее нужно заключить в **двойные кавычки**.

```
$Data = explode("\n", $content);
```

Не забывайте о том, что символ переноса строки зависит от используемой системы. Он может быть определен как `\n`, `\r` или `\r\n`.

Правильнее будет использовать предопределенную константу, которая покрывает все эти случаи:

```
$Data = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
```

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь готовой функцией file.

```
$data = file('myfile.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте построчное чтение файла. [fgets](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgets.php)

```
$handle = @fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $Data = array();
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        $Data[] = $buffer;
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
var_dump($Data);
```